# Is there an IntelliJ action or shortcut that allows creating a new separate file from existing code

Tags: intellij-idea

I quite often create multiple classes in one file and then split that file into multiple based on the classes or functions I have created.  Is there a way to extract a selection of code and create a new file from it in IntelliJ?  Part of the refactoring stuff maybe?  (I think this is possible in resharper)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Refactor | **Move Class** to move the class into a separate file:

[image: Move class]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't get that option.  I looked in the intentions section of Preferences and saw there was an option for Java but not for Dart.  Is there a way to add to the list of intentions myself or is it simply not supported or is intentions not the place to look (I get rename, move & copy file, extract; I don't get change signature, safe delete, inline super classs)

Comment: @orangesherbert It's not supported for Dart at the moment, see the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15198). You should have specified the language in your question since the supported refactorings are different.

Comment: Many thanks (yes, I didn't realise these options were language specific but that makes sense)

Comment: @orangesherbert see also the comment from the responsible developer: "Refactorings are now powered by the Dart Analysis Server from the Dart SDK. Adding IDE specific refactorings is not a high priority, I suggest to file a feature request in the Dart SDK issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues".